# Can OpenLayers be used to show/edit electrical Single Line Diagram (SLD)

Tags: openlayers, geojson, sql-server, restful

I have some spatial data source(SQL server tables with geometry fields) that contain
spatial data for single line diagram or SLD(here does not stand for styled layer descriptor) of electrical networks. This spatial data do not have a standard coordination system and I can fetch features with GeoJSON format from database.I can also provide a RESTful web service to get GeoJSON format features from database as data source.if we imagine each table as a single layer,each layer contais only points or line strings.Lines are drawn orthogonal and all lines are vertical or horizontal.

I need to develope a web application to :
-show these diagrams on the client browser with special symbology(line with different
color and width,points with different bitmaps depending on feature attributes)

```
-show some labels beside each feature based on some feature attributes
-user can delete a point or line feature depend on database permission
-user can move a line or point feature,add or delete vertices to/from a line string feature
-user can edit labels of feature
```

My question is :**Does OpenLayers can provide all these functionalities on client side?**Is there any other choice (more popular than OpenLayers) that covers these features and have advantages over OpenLayers?
Each single line diagrams contains less than 1000 features at all,but for some cases user needs to load even 100 diagrams (but no more than 2 diagrams can be edited) at the same time on his browser.

Comment: If your data source is GeoJSON, all required actions are available in OpenLayers out of the box, except editing feature labels, which would require a bit of additional coding.

Comment: You mean editing feature labels is still possible in Openlayers with additional coding?Needs some other libraries? Or only needs more scripting in OpenLayers?

Comment: Editing feature labels would require some JS scripting in OL.